# How To Have Several Onclicks In One Row (HTML/CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

So, this is my problem. I am making a home page and I am trying to get it so when you click on the buttons it will change the color of the button. That is all I have for them yet but they will do more later. Anyways, I already have the divs and all that but I can't get three of my buttons to work. Only the first one works. Check it out

CSS

```
body {
  background: #2F4F4F;
}
#as {
  width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#Home, #Alt, #News, #Contact {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 160px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#Home:hover, #Alt:hover, #News:hover, #Contact:hover {
  background: #6495ED;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div id = "as"></div>
  <div id = "Home" onclick = "Chb()">Home</div>
  <div id = "Alt" onclick = "Cvb()">Versions</div>
  <div id = "News" onclick = "Cnb()">News</div>
  <div id = "Contact" onclick = "Ccb()">Contact</div>
```

JS

```
function Chb() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#A9A9A9";
  document.getElementById("Versions").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#5F9EA09";
}
function Cvb() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Versions").style.background = "#A9A9A9";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#5F9EA09";
}
function Cnb() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Versions").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#A9A9A9";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#5F9EA09";
}
function Ccb() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Versions").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#A9A9A9";
}
```

And so whenever I click on the home button, it does what I wanted it to do but when I click any of the other buttons, it does not work. I believe this may be part of the `display: inline-block;` and if it is that, please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you you're trying to reference an `id` of 'Versions' instead of `Alt`.  Change it to either but keep it consistent.  Secondly, you can pass `this` to the callback function you assign to a `<div>`'s `onclick` handler to reduce the size of your code.

[Here's a working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tugenipilu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

---

Amended code:

HTML:

```
<div id = "Home" onclick = "newFunction(this)">Home</div>
<div id = "Alt" onclick = "newFunction(this)">Versions</div>
<div id = "News" onclick = "newFunction(this)">News</div>
<div id = "Contact" onclick = "newFunction(this)">Contact</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function newFunction(e) {
  // set all divs to one colour
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Alt").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#5F9EA09";

  // set the one clicked on to another
  document.getElementById(e.id).style.background = "#A9A9A9";
}
```

---

*Even shorter Javascript version (won't work in jsbin or codepen):*

```
function newFunction(e) {
  var divNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('#Home,#Alt,#News,#Contact');
  [].slice.call(divNodeList,0)
    .forEach(function(div){ div.style.background = "#5F9EA0" });

  document.getElementById(e.id).style.background = "#A9A9A9";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `id` called `Versions`, only `Alt`. Change it and ta da!

```js
function Chb() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#A9A9A9";
  document.getElementById("Alt").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#5F9EA09";
}
function Cvb() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Alt").style.background = "#A9A9A9";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#5F9EA09";
}
function Cnb() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Alt").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#A9A9A9";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#5F9EA09";
}
function Ccb() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Alt").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("News").style.background = "#5F9EA0";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.background = "#A9A9A9";
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #2F4F4F;
}
#as {
  width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#Home, #Alt, #News, #Contact {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 160px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#Home:hover, #Alt:hover, #News:hover, #Contact:hover {
  background: #6495ED;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id = "as"></div>
  <div id = "Home" onclick = "Chb()">Home</div>
  <div id = "Alt" onclick = "Cvb()">Versions</div>
  <div id = "News" onclick = "Cnb()">News</div>
  <div id = "Contact" onclick = "Ccb()">Contact</div>
```

Another solution using one function.

```js
function Cb(e) {
  //For this to work, you can't use the class "js-active" anywhere else.
  active = document.getElementsByClassName("js-active");
  
  if (active.length > 0) {
    active[0].style.background = "";
    active[0].classList.remove("js-active");
  }
  
  e.className += " js-active";
  
  //Instead of the previous line of code, you could also have:
  //#some-id .js-active {
  //  background: #A9A9A9;
  //}
  //To override the initial CSS, just add an id to the CSS selector, maybe the page wrapper's.
  document.getElementsByClassName("js-active")[0].style.background = "#A9A9A9";
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #2F4F4F;
}

#as {
  width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#Home,
#Alt,
#News,
#Contact {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 160px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#Home:hover,
#Alt:hover,
#News:hover,
#Contact:hover {
  background: #6495ED;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="as"></div>
<div id="Home" onclick="Cb(this)">Home</div>
<div id="Alt" onclick="Cb(this)">Versions</div>
<div id="News" onclick="Cb(this)">News</div>
<div id="Contact" onclick="Cb(this)">Contact</div>
```